# How to split a struct in Golang according to specific values

Tags: dataframe, go, data-structures, struct

I have a Python and R background and I am used to work with dataframes. 
If I have a following table:

```
>>> table

ID        Phone   Email Value
------------------------------
ID1  15555555555    None  None
ID2         None  3Email  None
ID3         3123  4Email   aaa
```

deriving two tables from `table` would look like this:

```
>>> table1=table[["ID","Phone","Email"]]
>>> table1

ID        Phone   Email
------------------------
ID1  15555555555    None
ID2         None  3Email
ID3         3123  4Email

>>> table2=table[["ID","Value"]]
>>> table2

ID Value
---------
ID1  None
ID2  None
ID3   aaa
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same with Golang. Below is my first step:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

type Identification struct {
    ID    string
    Phone int64
    Email string
    Value string
}

func main() {
    // define slice of Identification
    var idents []Identification
    idents = append(idents, Identification{ID: "ID1", Phone: 15555555555})
    idents = append(idents, Identification{ID: "ID2", Email: "3Email"})
    idents = append(idents, Identification{ID: "ID3",   Phone:3123, Email: "4Email", Value: "aaa"})

    fmt.Println(idents)

}
```

Result:

```
[{ID1 15555555555  } {ID2 0 3Email } {ID3 3123 3Email aaa}]
```

My question is how can I slice `idents`the same way I did with Python in the example?

Comment: A `struct` has a fixed "shape", so you cannot do this directly. Why do you want to though? You can just leave the fields there, and ignore them while processing.

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. What is your end goal?

Comment: @Flimzy my goal is to import row data from a source and then slice it according to specific keys and insert it into different tables in a database

Comment: There's no need to "slice" it in the structs, then. Just insert only the columns you care about into the respective tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures in go cannot be split, all you could do is reset the values of the fields you want to get rid of.

You'd need a `map` to achieve what you see in Python. But Go is a typed language,so in order to store arbitrary data you can use the `interface{}` type. Therefore you'd need to do it with an `map[string]interface{}` as you are storing data of different types, otherwise make everything strings and use `map[string]string`.

Then for slicing, well go doesn't have anything in the standard package to slice columns. Luckily, some people have worked on opensource packages to make your life easier :) I suggest you that one https://github.com/go-gota/gota

If you'd have to do it yourself, you could do that:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type table []map[string]interface{}

func (t table) sliceColumns(cols ...string) table {
        // create our new resulting table
        var newTable = make(table, len(t))

        // loop through table and populate our newTable
        for i, m := range t {

                var n = make(map[string]interface{}, len(cols))
                for _, col := range cols {
                        if v, ok := m[col]; ok {
                                n[col] = v
                        }
                }

                newTable[i] = n
        }

        return newTable
}

func main() {
        // define slice of Identification
        var t = table{
                {
                        "ID":    "1",
                        "Phone": 155555,
                },
                {
                        "ID":    "2",
                        "Email": "3Email",
                },
                {
                        "ID":    "3",
                        "Email": "4Email",
                        "Value": "aaaa",
                        "Phone": "123",
                },
        }

        fmt.Println(t.sliceColumns("ID", "Phone")) // [map[ID:1 Phone:155555] map[ID:2] map[ID:3 Phone:123]]
}
```